# Rails order by closest match of specific field when searching with multiple field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sorting, search

I've a search posts function in my website. It allow user to search posts by title & content. I want to prioritize the match result of `search by title` over `search by content`.

For example :

Post

```
id 1
title "Sample Title"
content "Content 1"

id 2
title "Random"
content "But it contains Title here"
```

When searching with query "Title", I want it to return both result but prioritize id 1 over 2.

What I've tried to do:

Post model:

```
scope :search_by_title, -> (keyword) {
  return if keyword.nil?
  where('title LIKE ?', "%#{sanitize_sql_like(keyword)}%")
}
scope :search_by_content, -> (keyword) {
  return if keyword.nil?
  where('content LIKE ?', "%#{sanitize_sql_like(keyword)}%")
}
```

Then in my controller:

```
 @posts_by_title = Post.search_by_name(query)
 @posts_by_content = Post.search_by_content(query)
 @posts = @posts_by_title + @posts_by_content
```

It works but it need to do query 2 times. So I'm just wondering is there any better way to achieve this result?

Comment: do you know about `gem searchkick` ?

Comment: @Vishal I haven't try that gem yet, but is it worth to use that gem for solving this problem?

Comment: yes, you will get lots functions with using this gem, under the hood searchkick gem use elastic search. i am sure you are aware about elastic search

Answer (score 0):

You could instead solve this programmatically. Query all the posts in your controller into an array and work on it, ensuring only one hit to the database to pull everything you need. That it should be `id`, `title` and `content` in your case.

Then in the array filter out non-matching posts, keep the matching ones and sort them following your criteria.